# Random TCP errors with the Gmail /Google API

Tags: heroku, google-api, dns, gmail, gmail-api

Since yesterday we are seeing randomly error with the gmail API :

Failed to open TCP connection to [www.googleapis.com:443](http://www.googleapis.com:443) (Network is unreachable - connect(2) for [2a00:1450:400b:c03::5f]:443)

It suddenly started at 10:24AM yesterday. Last week we've already experienced something like this for 24h and it has disappeared without any changes on our side.

We are hosted on Heroku, I'm currently thinking of a DNS change, ipv4/v6 issues or something like this.

Comment: stackoverflow is for programming. Try https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/ or even superuser. Also you probably need to provide a lot more details.

Comment: Ask your network administrator, your IPv6 connectivity is broken.